# ios storyboard logic

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

Let's say I have three `views` on my `storyboard`.

- *View 1* contains an `input field` and a `button`.
- the `input field` is where the user puts their answer for "2 + 2"
- *View 2* contains a message of "move on to the first grade!"
- *View 3* contains a message of "you are terrible at math.."

I want to link *View 1* and *View 2* using the storyboard, but I want to run logic when the button is touched on *View 1*.

If the input field is `== 4` then you are taken to *View 2* and if not then you are taken to *View 3*. Is something like this possible with `storyboarding`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

In storyboard create a segue from View 1 to View 2 by control-dragging from view controller 1 to view controller 2. Click on the segue and give it and identifier (view2 for example). Do the same thing to create a segue from View 1 to View 3 (give it and identifier view3).

Then in your view1 view controller code add the following code when the in the IBAction method for the button:

```
if (input == 4) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"view2" sender: self];
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"view3" sender: self];
}
```

In addition you can a prepareForSegue method to the view1 view controller where you can set properties on the destination view controllers:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"view2"]) 
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setSelectedClient:selectedClient];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setAddNoteViewControllerDelegate:self];
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"view3"]) 
    {
        // set properties for view3 view controller
    }
}
```